# Merging vertical space and and double spacing

Tags: line-spacing

I need to implement the following formatting in LaTeX:

```
ABSTRACT
<3 single spaces>
THESIS TITLE
<3 single spaces>
Double spaced text
```

Right now, I'm getting the following (I added the gray rectangles to compare the heights before and after the title - the rectangles are the same height):

[image: What I'm getting]

As you can see, there's a little bit of extra space before the first line of text. What I really want is something like this:

[image: What I want]

What's the cleanest way to achieve this? Here's my file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{THIS IS THE TITLE OF MY THESIS}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\makeatletter

\singlespacing

{\centering

ABSTRACT

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

\@title

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

}

\doublespacing

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent mi diam, porta eget magna a, tempor vulputate dui. Cras elementum tellus sed odio varius bibendum. Suspendisse cursus leo vitae imperdiet laoreet. Donec efficitur vel nisl quis consequat. Praesent lobortis non neque nec rhoncus. Pellentesque eget lacus egestas, scelerisque dolor in, congue augue. Praesent ultrices dui ut urna fermentum, nec posuere ante gravida. Proin luctus et leo ac rhoncus. In et tellus ut mi porttitor efficitur vel et lacus. Vivamus lacus augue, bibendum id nisl ultricies, aliquam lacinia enim.

Nam volutpat, ligula in fringilla lacinia, ligula arcu imperdiet orci, quis pharetra metus odio pellentesque nunc. Etiam at diam nibh. Suspendisse venenatis lectus sit amet urna rhoncus ornare. Curabitur eget neque risus. Sed fringilla, tortor molestie ultrices posuere, turpis sapien maximus erat, nec dignissim justo neque quis eros. Sed sit amet nisi sit amet leo dignissim cursus. Aenean iaculis massa dolor, nec ultrices dui egestas vitae. Sed vitae vulputate velit. Praesent vitae commodo nisl, nec ultricies odio. Praesent vitae porttitor tellus. Sed sed hendrerit mauris. Donec sed nibh erat. Etiam vel posuere nisi, eget commodo neque. Integer pharetra sagittis nisi ac auctor. Morbi id lectus ornare metus pharetra pulvinar eu et odio. Aliquam eleifend fringilla erat, sed ultricies ipsum viverra vitae.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add these tracing commands after first paragraph and after empty line:

```
\showboxdepth=0 \showboxbreadth=100 \showlists
```

Now, you can see in .log file, that your thinking about vertical spaces between lines is totally different from TeX thinking. The main register which controls interlines spacing is `\baselineskip` and there is a tendency to set distance between baselines to this value, no to set interlineskip from bottom of one line to the top of next. You can see this:

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\write-{}
\glue(\topskip) 3.8
\hbox(8.2+0.0)x469.75502, glue set 201.75563fil []
\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
\penalty 10000
\glue 43.5
\glue 0.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 6.3
\hbox(8.2+0.0)x469.75502, glue set 133.31396fil []
\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
\penalty 10000
\glue 43.5
\glue 0.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 15.66417
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set - 0.68553 []
\penalty 150
\glue(\baselineskip) 13.33086
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set 0.62148 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 13.33086
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set 0.01955 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 13.33086
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set 0.07323 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 13.33086
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set 0.29207 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 13.33086
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set 0.16704 []
\penalty 150
\glue(\baselineskip) 13.33086
\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x469.75502, glue set 276.73064fil []
total height 281.48238 plus 2.0
 goal height 650.43001
prevdepth 2.33331, prevgraf 7 lines
```

First, you see that the space before the first line (ABSTRACT) is set to 3.8 pt in order to the distance from top to baseline of the first line is 12 pt (`\topskip` value). Then there is space 3*14.5 pt = 43.5 pt from your `\vskip 3\baselineskip` because `\baselineskip` is set to 14.5 pt. Then there is a space before second line (TITLE) 6.3 pt because the distance from this point to the baseline of the title line should be 14.5 pt, i.e. one `\baselineskip` (previous box with ABSTRACT in the page has had zero depth). Then there is second 43.5 pt space. Then there is space 15.66417 pt from `\baselineskip` (now its value is 25 pt) in order the baseline of the first line of the paragraph should be in 25 pt distance from the previous point.

If you don't need this first 15.66417 space in your vertical list then put `\nointerlineskip` before the first paragraph. If you don't need the space 6.3 pt before the title line then put `\nointerlineskip` before the title line.